# Is it possible to get service by module name in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

Lets consider the situatiton - there are N modules and all of them have the service of the same interface (`com.foo.SomeService`). Is it possible to get this service by module name (`my.module`) without iterating all services of all modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell if this is a real question or not. The right way to select a service provider is by probing its capabilities, meaning design a good service interface so that consumers have enough to select an appropriate implementation.

If this question is about configuring something to use a specific service provider then it is not difficult to select by module name if you really need to:

```
ServiceLoader.load(service).stream()
        .filter(p -> "X".equals(p.type().getModule().getName()))
        .map(Provider::get)
        .findAny();
```

Answer (score 2):

The **[`ModuleDescriptor.Provides`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.Provides.html#service--)** can provide the name of the service provided by the Module.

```
Module module; // representation for your 'my.module'
Set<ModuleDescriptor.Provides> provides = module.getDescriptor().provides();
provides.forEach(p -> {
    System.out.println("service - " + p.service());
    System.out.println("providers - " + p.providers());
});
```

Where for e.g. if the module declaration is as follows :

```
module my.module {
    ...
    provides java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement with AnnotateElemenImpl; 
}
```

where `AnnotateElemenImpl` class provides the implemenation of an interface `AnnotatedElement` from `java.lang.reflect` module. The above shared code segment would return details as :

```
service - java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement
providers - [com.module.AnnotateElemenImpl]
```